# How can I write a C++ function that returns different types of std::list based on processing?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, stdlist

What is wrong with below code at the indicated points? I want to return list of integers or characters or strings based on what program read somewhere in a file. I tried below code but it throws me error. I am a bit weak with templates as you can see.

```
template <class T> 
std::list<T> function1(int type)
{
   using namespace std;
   if (1 == type)
      return list<int>(3, 100); / No error
   else if (2 == type){
      list<wchar_t> temp;
      temp.push_back(L'a');  // C2664 error here
      return temp;
   }else if (3 == type){
      list<wstring> temp;
      temp.push_back(L"a"); // C2664 error here
      return temp;
   }else
      return nullptr;   // C2664 error here
}
```

I have pointed out the points where "visual studio 2013 community edition update 4" throws compiler error C2664. How can I write like this where I can get the list based on the processing inside? One of the error is below.

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'std::list<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::list(std::initializer_list<_Ty>,const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::list<wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t>>' to 'const std::list<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. You should make [template specializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) instead of forcing returns of various types.

Comment: This is not possible in C++ (Unless you go the dreadful type elision road, which requires a different design)

Comment: Is `type` known at compile time or run time? Also, `list<int>` is rarely a good idea.

Comment: What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?  I can see a number of red flags -- you used `std::list<>` which is rarely a good idea, you want to take run time data and switch into a compile-time type, you described a problem with a small detail of a problem without describing the bigger problem you are trying to solve, you failed to provide a test harness describing how your code is called, you think `nullptr` can be converted to an instance of a non-pointer.  By any chance, are you used to java/C# Generics?

Comment: Type will be one of the standard type. I am taking input from user in file which can be one of the standard type. Multiple classes will use it at multiple points, hence trying to keep it generic by returning a STL data type. Callers would know the type so they can deduce further.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, templates need to be resolved during compile-time but the value of `type` is not known there. You would need to use some indirection such as [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/) or non-templated interface. Or rather use a completely different approach.

Comment: And what could be an alternative approach besides function overloading?

Comment: You can template the function itself or maybe have a think about the whole program flow, if it really needs to construct different lists using one function.

Comment: Here what's needed is `boost::variant<>` _and_ a non-templated interface. Possibly even a `boost::optional<boost::variant<>>`, to account for the final `else` condition, but that would probably be better handled with a sentinal type inside of the variant directly.

Answer (score 0):

In other words: the template itself does not contain enough information for it to be compiled. You need to instantiate a it by supplying the template arguments when you use the template; the compiler cannot decide to figure out its arguments later (or it would probably involve some just-in-time compilation). I don't think you can use specialization to work around this, because the return types would not be compatible. (Sorry that I wrote a new answer... I do not yet have the privilege to comment...)

It would be hard to decide the type of the objects in the `list` and then return it or a pointer to it so that you can use it in the function that called `function1`. You can consider refactoring your code. If possible, you can try calling other functions that do further processing from within the function instead.

If you are adamant on returning the list from `function1`: <s>one idea that I can think of is to create a wrapper class that contains a `void*` pointer to the list (dynamically allocated), and something that tells you the type (say, `int type`). But then other functions would probably have to follow this pattern.</s> JK. (It would definitely create more trouble that it solves.)

Answer (score -1):

For any instantiation of your function template on any particular type, at least one literal is likely to be incompatible with that type.

You can use specializations of some traits class that provides values of the various supported types. This makes it easy to support new types. Or you can just use overloads of the function for the various supported types.